# Xamarin Forms will randomly refuse to build throwing all sorts of reference errors, restart and it works fine

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I will be happily coding along, everything is working fine, then randomly - I will get a massive stack of errors pertaining to Xamarin.Forms.  Nothing has changed, I can clean and attempt rebuilding all I want but it will not work.  Sometimes I can close VS and re-open and it will work, sometimes I have to restart.  This is INCREDIBLY annoying, not to mention time consuming.  Has anyone run into this?  I will attach screens of errors:

[image]

Comment: It happens sometimes. Either is a IDE Bug, which you should delete bin/obj, restart Visual Studio, or some error in your code  that cascades to all those errors.

Comment: Ugh... that is a huge pain - I am going to put in a support ticket - this is unacceptable for relatively expensive software.

Comment: "Sometimes" here would be the understatement of the century. Working with Xamarin requires so much patience you'll achieve zen in no time. For the last 7 months or so I've had these kind of issue on a daily basis. All you can do is  what @BrunoCaceiro said.said.